# Delay between fadein and fadeout of images in slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just created a sample slick slider with fadein and fadeout effect. I want to add a once second delay between fadein and fadeout effect of these slider images. i.e after fadeout of once slide image there should be one second gap to the next slider image fadein. Below is my code and code pen link.

**Here is Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    fade:true,
    autoplay: true,
    speed: 2000,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    pauseOnHover:true,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 767,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">

  <div class="img-container"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/26/16/39/beach-3352363_960_720.jpg">

  </div> 

  <div class="img-container"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/26/16/31/marine-3352341_960_720.jpg">

  </div> 

  <div class="img-container"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/08/20/03/flag-1244649_960_720.jpg">

  </div> 

</div>
```

Code pen Link: https://codepen.io/dSaif/pen/ExaaQJV

Please help me how can i do this

Comment: Instead of  speed: 2000 make  speed: 1000  in jquery code

Comment: use `autoplaySpeed: 1000`.. Default autoplay speed in slick is `3000`. So you autoplay speed as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi @Supriya & Asfan i want the one second gap between the slides. i.e the first slide image need to complete fadout and need to get gap of one second and after that the next slide image should fadein.

Comment: That's not a standard option of Slick... you will have to either mend the Slick JS code or you could insert a transparent image between each slide, but then you'll get a pause equal to your speed, so 2 seconds.

Comment: thank you @ ChrisBE for you response, Please let me know what are all the changes should i need to do in slick js

Comment: When slide fade out it took `2000`ms and when slide fade in it took `2000`ms as well. So, total timing is `4000`ms. But you need `1000`ms hold on slide. So, you have to set `autoplaySpeed: 5000` in slick options.

Comment: @Afsan, its not working as per my requirement. its just giving 5000 ms of time for fadein and fadeout

Comment: anybody, please help me on this

Comment: If you still haven't figured this out yet, you might wanna look at the top comment on here: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. Looks like you would have to set autoPlay to false and use JS to change slides.